# UIWebView Scaling not the same as Safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm working on a small UIWebView iOS App which points to my website, i've set the viewports correctly and it looks great in safari or if i add a bookmark to my home screen

But for some reason when i plug it into the UIWebView everything is larger, i tried unchecking "Scale to Fit" for the UIWebView in interface builder, but that dont help

How can i keep the WebView to scale/show things at the same aspect of safari?

Code in WebSite Header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<title>SITE TITLE</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{$url}/favicon.ico" />
<link href="{$url}/{$theme_path}/{$theme_name}/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="WEBAPPICON.png"/>
</head>
```

Code for UIWebView:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Webview
//
//  Created by Stewart Crainie on 10/02/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Stewart Crainie. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize receivedData, theConnection, webSite, back, forward, stop, refresh;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [self loadWebsite];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}



- (void)loadWebsite {


    NSString *fullURL = @"http://WEBVITEURL";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestWebsite = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    [webSite loadRequest:requestWebsite];
}

- (void)updateButtons
{
    self.forward.enabled = self.webSite.canGoForward;
    self.back.enabled = self.webSite.canGoBack;
    self.stop.enabled = self.webSite.loading;

}

#pragma mark MBProgressHUDDelegate methods

- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    HUD = nil;
}


-(void)stopLoading {

    NSLog(@"Stop Pushed");
    [HUD hide:YES];
    [webSite stopLoading];


}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"could not load the website caused by error: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                         message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];
    [HUD hide:YES];
    [webSite stopLoading];

}


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


    [self updateButtons];

    [HUD hide:YES];
    [webSite stopLoading];
}


-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {


    [self updateButtons];

    HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading...";

}

@end
```

Comment: I have the same question. Any body?